# How can I get white balance support for Canon EOS 1100D in UFRaw?

Tags: software, raw, white-balance, canon-1100d, ufraw

I have a Canon EOS 1100D and I'd like to edit my raw pictures using Gimp.
I've installed Ufraw but it says that there are is no white balance presets for my camera model.

How can I make it work and edit my pictures in GIMP?

Answer (score 5):

Canon EOS 1100D white balance presents have been [commited to ufraw source](http://ufraw.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ufraw/ufraw/wb_presets.c?r1=1.179&r2=1.180) at 2011 July. Either install an ufraw binary version which was created later, or you might compile your own version.

Comment: Thanks, I've compiled the cvs sources and it seems to work. I guess this feature will appear in 0.19.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can try using RawTherapee or DarkTable, I managed to open CR2 files from my EOS 1100D without problems.